# How to connect comboboxes from a dynamic Table Widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I am trying to create a Table Widget, whose number of rows varies according to a SpinBox.

This I managed to do. In each cell for row the Table Widget I have a ComboBox.

I need to connect the combobox for each row of the Table Widget. When selecting the "Country" automatically in the next two combobox, the option for "Capital" and the corresponding "City" appear.

For example when selecting Country "USA":

- Capital: Washington
- City: Chicago, New York

I am putting the code to make it clearer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.spin)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for col, label in enumerate(('Country', 'Capital', 'City')):
            header = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(label)
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(col, header)

        self.spin.setValue(self.table.rowCount())
        self.spin.valueChanged.connect(self.setRowCount)

    def setRowCount(self, count):
        if count == self.table.rowCount():
            return
        # if there are too many rows, remove them
        while self.table.rowCount() > count:
            self.table.removeRow(self.table.rowCount() - 1)
        # if rows are going to be added, create checkable items for them
        while self.table.rowCount() < count:
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(row)

            dic = {"Country": ['Argentina', 'USA', 'Spain'], "Capital": ['Buenos Aires', 'Washington D.C.','Madrid'], "City1": ["Rosario", "Chicago", "Barcelona"],
                   "City2": ["Bariloche", "New York", "Osasuna"]}
            
            for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                if i==0:
                    combobox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox1.addItems(dic["Country"])
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox1)                    
                elif i==1:
                    combobox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox2.addItems(dic["Capital"])
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox2)
                elif i==2:
                    combobox3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox3.addItems(dic["City1"])
                    combobox3.addItems(dic["City2"])
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the dict and city info with same indexing then it is pretty easy with your current code. But I am not sure is it efficient system to do like this.

Anyway here is a working solution with your current code

```
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dic = {"Country": ['Argentina', 'USA', 'Spain'], "Capital": ['Buenos Aires', 'Washington D.C.','Madrid'], "City1": ["Rosario", "Chicago", "Barcelona"],
                   "City2": ["Bariloche", "New York", "Osasuna"]}
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.spin)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for col, label in enumerate(('Country', 'Capital', 'City')):
            header = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(label)
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(col, header)

        self.spin.setValue(self.table.rowCount())
        self.spin.valueChanged.connect(self.setRowCount)

    def setRowCount(self, count):
        if count == self.table.rowCount():
            return
        # if there are too many rows, remove them
        while self.table.rowCount() > count:
            self.table.removeRow(self.table.rowCount() - 1)
        # if rows are going to be added, create checkable items for them
        while self.table.rowCount() < count:
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(row)
            
            for i in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                if i==0:
                    combobox1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox1.addItems(self.dic["Country"])
                    combobox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(partial(self.updateCity, row))
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox1)                    
                elif i==1:
                    combobox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox2.addItems(self.dic["Capital"])
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox2)
                elif i==2:
                    combobox3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    combobox3.addItems(self.dic["City1"])
                    self.table.setCellWidget(row, i, combobox3)

    def updateCity(self, index):
        current_index = self.sender().currentIndex()
        capital_widget = self.table.cellWidget(index, 1)
        city_widget = self.table.cellWidget(index, 2)
        capital_widget.setCurrentIndex(current_index)
        city_widget.setCurrentIndex(current_index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```